# How to get rid of IndexOutOfBoundsException from ArrayList

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

When I start my server and a client connects to it I get this error:

```
Waiting for clients ...
Client connected from: Driton PC
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

I do not quite understand why this happens when I have followed after another from the internet and his example works and my does not

```
public class ChatServer { 

public static ArrayList<Socket> ConnectionArray = new ArrayList<Socket>();

public static ArrayList<String> CurrentUsers = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    try
    {
        final int PORT = 444;
        ServerSocket SERVER = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");

        while(true)
        {
            Socket SOCK = SERVER.accept();
            ConnectionArray.add(SOCK);
            System.out.println("Client connected from: "+ SOCK.getLocalAddress().getHostName());
            AddUserName(SOCK);
            Chat_Server_Return CHAT = new Chat_Server_Return(SOCK);
            Thread x = new Thread(CHAT); 
            x.start();
        }
    }
        catch(Exception x){System.out.println(x);}
}

public static void AddUserName(Socket X) throws IOException
{
    Scanner INPUT = new Scanner(X.getInputStream());
    String UserName = INPUT.nextLine();
    CurrentUsers.add(UserName);
    for(int i = 1; 1 <= ChatServer.ConnectionArray.size(); i++){
        Socket TEMP_SOCK = (Socket) ChatServer.ConnectionArray.get(i-1);
        PrintWriter OUT = new PrintWriter(TEMP_SOCK.getOutputStream());
        OUT.println("#?!"+ CurrentUsers);
        OUT.flush();

    }
}
```

It runs the `for` loop twice.

Comment: `i` needs to start at 0, not 1, and the for condition should be `i < ChatServer.ConnectionArray.size()`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - However, inside the loop, OP is using `i-1` to index the ArrayList.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Changing the loop condition to be `i <= ...` instead of `1 <= ...` fixes the problem. My comment was about starting at 0 and ending at `i < ...`. This is unnecessary since OP is using `i-1` inside the loop. If you change the loop limits without changing `get(i-1)` to `get(i)`, you'll get an index error on the first iteration.

Comment: @TedHopp Yeah, he's got to change his whole iteration strategy basically.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - All he needs to do is change the `1` to an `i`. :)

Comment: @TedHopp You are correct. But he's better off doing things correctly. People are going to ask what the hell is `i - 1` for? You'll usually do that when you want to compare 2 items at a time, not when you're iterating with single index.

Answer (score 5):

The condition for the `for` loop is incorrect if nothing is ever removed.  Change to:

```
i <= ChatServer.ConnectionArray.size()
```

But the conventional way of processing a for loop is to follow the 0-based index and *not* subtract one later:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ChatServer.ConnectionArray.size(); i++){
    Socket TEMP_SOCK = (Socket) ChatServer.ConnectionArray.get(i);
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the exception; OP is calling `get(i-1)`, not `get(i)`. The loop limits seem to be correct.

Comment: @Ted Hopp Yes it does.  It's an infinite loop because presumably the size of the collection never drops below 1.  Eventually the code runs off the end because 1 (one) always remains less than or equal to the collection size.

Comment: either of the two option i got didnt work from  Sotirios Delimanolis and rgettman

Comment: The full answer by @rgettman is correct. If you are getting another exception, post it.

Comment: @DritonCazimi - Use your original code, but change the loop continuation test from `1 <= ...` to `i <= ...`. It should then work. (The original code appears to be a typo. It can be hard to distinguish a `1` from an `i`.)

Comment: i'll when i get home. but i dont understand how this dude code is working but not my code.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uo5DY546rKY

Comment: @Driton Cazimi - I doubt that the original code you copied ever worked.

Comment: @DritonCazimi The dude in the video is using `i <= ChatServer.Co...` you're using `1 <= ...`

Comment: I googled the code just now and found http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/287459-problem-with-chat-program/, which _does_ use `i <= Chat_Server.ConnectionArray.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy with performing checks for array length.

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` really thrown when accessing a collection rather that array.

There's one variety of this exception known `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` which is similar but the purpose to resolve the same just use checks for the size of the collection to make sure you are not out of it's bounty.